# Symfony - Simple @Route doens't seem to work as expected

Tags: php, symfony

I just started on Symfony so I'm trying to learn Routing. Therefore, accordingly with official documentation about [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html), I made a simple page like this:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/index", name="Players lister")
    */
    public function renderFirstPage()
    {
        return $this->render('accounts.html.twig');
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/index/{account}", name="Players lister")
    */
    public function getPlayersList($account)
    {
        $players = array("Player1", "Player2");
        return $this->render('accounts.html.twig', array(
            'account' => $account,
            'players' => $players
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

But when I go at `http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/index` I get `No route found for "GET /index"` while the second Route works good. Instead, if I delete the second Route, the first one works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Routes are indexed by name in the order they are found. So as your 2 routes have the same name the second is over writing the first. Give the routes unique names and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each route registered in [Symfony's Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) component should have unique URI and name.

> Each route also has an internal name: blog_list and blog_show. These can be anything (as long as each is unique) and don't have any meaning yet. Later, you'll use it to generate URLs.

Answer (score 1):

routing path and name should be uniq

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="home")
*/
public function renderFirstPage()
{
    return $this->render('accounts.html.twig');
}

/**
* @Route("/index/{account}", name=players_lister")
*/
public function getPlayersList($account)
{
    $players = array("Player1", "Player2");
    return $this->render('accounts.html.twig', array(
        'account' => $account,
        'players' => $players
    ));
}
```